# My new template file in WooCommerce doesn't work for products with tags

Tags: wordpress, tags, woocommerce, categories, product

I am new with WooCommerce, and I don't know how to solve this issue. I have product with categories and tag.

In my home page I show two lists, product by tags and product by categories.
When I click in my first list I have to show something like this:
*(return a list of this tag order by category)*

```
Tag1
Category 1  (2) number of products
Category 2  (4)
Category 3  (1)
```

and when I click in Category 1, I show a product like `product-tag.php` file

For do this I override woocommerce plugin and add this in `product-tag.php`:

```
if (is_product_category()) :
    include("product-category.php");
  else:
    if (is_product_tag()) :
      include("listTag-product.php");
    endif;
  endif;
```

`listTag-product.php` is a new file that I created, but don't work, by default call to `product-tag.php`.

How to change this?

I want to use `product_tag.php` when I click in the list "Category 1  (2)" to show the product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that a `product tag` can also be a `product category` or the opposite…

For that reason when using `if (is_product_category())` the condition is always `true` and `listTag-product.php` will **never be included**…

Looking at **WooCommerce templates**, I don't see any:

- `product_tag.php` template
- `product-category.php` template…

The related existing **WooCommerce templates** are:

- content-product_cat.php
- taxonomy-product_cat
- taxonomy-product_tag.php

After all why split this in 2 templates? You don't need that. You will better use the same template with fine tuned conditions inside it. But **using conditionals** as `is_product_category()` and `is_product_tag()` **together** is not the solution…

Depending on your thoughts, you could better use categories and subcategories instead of categories and tags.

If you want some real help, it will be better to reconsidering all, changing your approach and beginning to explore other ways. Here in Stackoverflow you will need to make a new question with more details and making available the code used in your templates or scripts, explaining with clarity, what is working and what not… *For each problem one question at the time.*

References:

- [Managing Product Categories, Tags and Attributes](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/managing-product-taxonomies/)
- [Display WooCommerce Categories, Subcategories, and Products in Separate Lists](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/display-woocommerce-categories-subcategories-and-products-in-separate-lists--cms-25479)

Comment: Thanks @LoicTheAztec I appreciate your help. You have reason, I am using now the template that have woocommerce by default.